# What does this syntax mean in c++

Tags: c++

I saw some code like below in C++ source:

```
size_t s1, s2 = sizeof(int), s3;
```

What does this mean?
Sorry for naive question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s multiple declaration (and arguably bad style) equivalent to:

```
size_t s1;
size_t s2 = sizeof(int);
size_t s3;
```

Comment: @jiych.guru I find it hard to call it "bad". On the contrary, because these are closely named variables most likely they are related and I'd keep declared on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Commas in c++ can work either as **Separators** or **Operators**.

As **separator**, it either:

applies the declaration to all the following expressions:

```
type a, b = 5, *c;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
type a;
type b = 5;
type *c;
```

or separates elements that should be grouped together:

int ray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

As an **operator**, comma is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

```
int a=1, b=2, c=3;
int i = (a += 2, c+1, a + b); // a = 3,  a + b = 5 --> i = 5
//Here, c + 1 is evaluated to 3+1 = 4, but the result remains unused
```

Here, each operand is evaluated consecutively, and the final operation `(a + b)`, becomes `i`'s value

By the way `sizeof(x)` is a function that returns the size in bytes of the variable, object x, or a type (`int` in this case).

It should be noted that when using `sizeof(ptr)` with a pointer parameter, it only returns the size of the pointer and not of the target.